# Jruby check if JavaMail headers contains a specific name

Tags: java, jruby, jakarta-mail

On a JavaMail POP3Message there's a method to get all header lines which returns an Enumeration of name and value. I know I can traverse this and check if a specific header name exists but am thinking there may be a better way to do that but can't find it. Is there any faster/better alternative solution than having to traverse everything from Jruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which header you're looking for, use one of the MimeMessage [getHeader](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) [methods](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks, weird how that escaped me while going through the API.